# Не получается вызвать следующую ф-цию через FSMContext

Tags: python, aiogram

Пытаюсь вызвать ф-цию password после сообщения 'Send username of participant'. В telebot можно было это сделать через register_next_step_handler, в aiogram это осуществить сложнее. Заранее спасибо тем, кто поможет!
Код:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def call(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    if callback.data=='admin':
        if callback.message.from_user.id == int(os.getenv('ADMIN_ID')):
            btn1=InlineKeyboardButton('Add user',callback_data='add')
            btn2=InlineKeyboardButton('Delete user',callback_data='delete')
            btn3=InlineKeyboardButton('Show user list',callback_data='list')

            mark_adm=InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            mark_adm.add(btn1,btn2)
            mark_adm.add(btn3)

            await callback.message.answer('You signed in as <b>admin!</b>',reply_markup=mark_adm,parse_mode='html')
        else:
            await callback.message.answer("<b><i>You're not admin</i></b>",parse_mode='html')
    if callback.data=='buy':
        await callback.message.answer(callback.message.from_user.id)
    if callback.data=='add':
        await callback.message.answer('Send username of participant')
        await state.set_state(password)



async def password(message: types.Message):
    global user
    user=message.text
    await message.answer('Create password for participant')
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите просто вызвать функцию, вам не нужно использовать

`await state.set_state(password)` вы можете её просто вызвать `password()`

Но я предполагаю что вы хотите изменить состояние для пользователя, чтобы он работал в функции `password` если это так для начала вам нужно зарегестрировать состояние, это можно сделать вот так:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

class Session(StatesGroup):
    password_state = State()

@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def call(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    if callback.data=='admin':
        if callback.message.from_user.id == int(os.getenv('ADMIN_ID')):
            btn1=InlineKeyboardButton('Add user',callback_data='add')
            btn2=InlineKeyboardButton('Delete user',callback_data='delete')
            btn3=InlineKeyboardButton('Show user list',callback_data='list')

            mark_adm=InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            mark_adm.add(btn1,btn2)
            mark_adm.add(btn3)

            await callback.message.answer('You signed in as <b>admin!</b>',reply_markup=mark_adm,parse_mode='html')
        else:
            await callback.message.answer("<b><i>You're not admin</i></b>",parse_mode='html')
    if callback.data=='buy':
        await callback.message.answer(callback.message.from_user.id)
    if callback.data=='add':
        await callback.message.answer('Send username of participant')
        await Session.password_state.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Session.password_state)
async def password(message: types.Message):
    global user
    user=message.text
    await message.answer('Create password for participant')
```

После нажатия кнопки "Add user" вы будете переходить в состояние `password_state = State()` это состояние привязано к функции `async def password(message: types.Message):` и все события будут происходить там

P.s. не рекомендую использовать `global` в своем коде, если вам нужно хранить какие-то данные в своем проекте, при этом не создавая базу данных, вы можете использовать хранилище state. Вот тут хорошо расписано про [хранилище и состояния](https://qna.habr.com/q/814053)